# Displaying First Item in an Array Inside the Controller.content[] Array

Tags: ember.js

How do I display a specific item in an array within my ArrayController.content[] property? I have this code below:

```
App.View.PairView = Em.View.create({    
  templateName: 'display-template',
  controller: App.Controller.PairController 
});


App.Controller.PairController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  createNew: function(){        
    var weeks = ['1','2','3'];
    var quarters = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'];
    var months = ['Jan', 'Sep', 'Dec'];

    this.set('content', []);
    this.pushObject(weeks);
    this.pushObject(quarters);
    this.pushObject(months);        
  }
});
```

I only want to get App.Controller.PairController.content[0][0] or the "weeks". How do i write that if I have the handlebars template below?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="display-template">
  {{#each item in controller}}                                                  
       ???????????????????????
   {{/each}}      
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by index .0 or .1 etc...

{{item.0.0}}